# Animation on RecyclerView when pulling data from firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-animation

I am trying to load my data (a collection of documents) which I have pulled from the firestore database into my RecylerView as an ArrayList of Events. While they do actually load, the animation doesn't show and I get a log stating 
`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`. I'm not sure if this is a reason as to why my animation doesn't load. I'd greatly appreciate if somebody would know how to correct my mistakes (if I had made any) so anyone that might end up having the same issue as me in the future could find their answer in this question.

The following are my activites:

```
package com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.otherHomePossibilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.R;
import com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.eventPerspective.Event;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private LinearLayoutManager rLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseFirestore  db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference eventsRef = db.collection("events");
    private ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    private TextView tv;
    private ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_event_for_perspective);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.activity_cefp_tv);
        pb = findViewById(R.id.activity_cefp_pb);
        pb.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.dirtierWhite), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        rv = findViewById(R.id.activity_cefp_rv);
        rLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity.this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(rLayoutManager);
        //refreshEventRV();
        eventsRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                events.clear();
                tv.setText(R.string.loading_events);
                String userEmail = user.getEmail();
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                    Event event = documentSnapshot.toObject(Event.class);
                    for(int i=0; i<event.getEmails_of_people().size();i++){
                        if(userEmail!=null){
                            if(event.getEmails_of_people().get(i).compareTo(userEmail)==0){
                                event.setEvent_id(documentSnapshot.getId());
                                events.add(event);
                                break;
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity.this, "[YERROR]: Email is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

                if(events.isEmpty()){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv.setText(R.string.no_events_to_choose_from);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    runAnimation(rv, 0);

                }

            }
        });

                /*eRoleAdapter = new ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter(events, ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity.this);
                rv.setAdapter(eRoleAdapter);
                int resId = R.anim.layout_animation_from_right;
                LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity.this, resId);
                rv.setLayoutAnimation(animation);*/



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshEventRV();
    }


    private void refreshEventRV(){

        eventsRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                events.clear();
                tv.setText(R.string.loading_events);
                String userEmail = user.getEmail();
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                    Event event = documentSnapshot.toObject(Event.class);
                    for(int i=0; i<event.getEmails_of_people().size();i++){
                        if(userEmail!=null){
                            if(event.getEmails_of_people().get(i).compareTo(userEmail)==0){
                                  event.setEvent_id(documentSnapshot.getId());
                                events.add(event);
                                break;
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity.this, "[YERROR]: Email is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

                if(events.isEmpty()){
                    tv.setText(R.string.no_events_to_choose_from);
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void runAnimation(RecyclerView rv, int type) {
        Context context = rv.getContext();
        LayoutAnimationController controller = null;

        if(type == 0){
            controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);
            ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter eRoleAdapter = new ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter(events, rv.getContext());
            rv.setAdapter(eRoleAdapter);

            rv.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
            rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            rv.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
        }

    }
}


package com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.otherHomePossibilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.R;
import com.washedup.anagnosti.ergo.eventPerspective.Event;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter.ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Event> events;
    private Context context;

    //private int lastPosition = -1;

    public ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Event> events, Context context){
        this.events=events;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective, parent,false);
        itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return new ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Event tempEvent = events.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.child_activity_cefp_et.setText(tempEvent.getEvent_name());
        //setAnimation(holder.itemView,position);

    }

   /* private void setAnimation(View itemView, int position) {
        if(position > lastPosition){
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_animation_from_right);
            itemView.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder holder) {

        (holder).clearAnimation();
    }*/

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    public class ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView child_activity_cefp_cv;
        EditText child_activity_cefp_et;
        ImageView child_activity_cefp_iv;
       // FrameLayout child_activity_cefp_container;

        public ChooseEventForPerspectiveRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            child_activity_cefp_cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_cv);
            child_activity_cefp_et = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_et);
            child_activity_cefp_iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_iv);
           // child_activity_cefp_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_item_layout_container);

        }

       /* public void clearAnimation() {
            child_activity_cefp_container.clearAnimation();
        }*/
    }
}
```

and these are my xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".otherHomePossibilities.ChooseEventForPerspectiveActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_cefp_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_cefp_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/loading_events"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/activity_cefp_pb"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_cefp_tv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_cv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_iv"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_linlay"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_linlay"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_iv"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/slider_info_event_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/child_activity_choose_event_for_perspective_et"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_from_right"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="10%" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_long">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

Hope I provided everything you need!